# Specify value type of NSDictionary entries

Tags: objective-c, generics, nsarray, nsdictionary

For an `NSArray`, Objective-C allows us to specify the type of the values to be stored in the array. For example, I can declare an array of `NSString`'s as follows:

```
NSArray<NSString*> *arrayOfStrings;
```

While it is not necessarily enforced by the compiler and runtime environment, such an indication can be handy both for readability and slightly simpler code syntax.

I was wondering if such a syntax existed for `NSDictionary`. For example, to specify the value type in the dictionary, does something like the following exist:

```
NSDictionary<UIImage*> *imageMappings;
```

where the dictionary's values are specified to be of type `UIImage`.

**Additional questions:**

Can key types be specified for `NSDictionary`?

If possible, how can I specify value type without key type?

Are there other common data structures in `Foundation` that have this generic parametrization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `NSDictionary`, you specify the type for both key and value:

```
NSDictionary<NSString*, UIImage*> *imageMappings
```

If you don't want a specific type for the key, use `id<NSCopying>` or even `NSObject *`.

Only `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` support this notation.

Comment: `id` or `id<NSCopying>` would be better than `NSObject *`

Comment: I didn't know if those were valid type specifiers.

Comment: I do not understand the answer - and it lacks the "how" semantics. could you please provide a single simple example of the syntax? I'm already trying 10 different ways, to no avail.

Comment: `NSDictionary<KeyType*, ValueType*> *myTypedDictionary`.